# Will my finepix s8600 be enough for the milky way

Tags: astrophotography, fujifilm, stars, night-photography, bridge-camera

I'm planning on buying a DSLR soon but impatience got me I decided to take my moms 4 year old bridge camera and give a shot, I took pictures in a mildly light polluted area, and it seemed to have gotten every star I could see with my own eye (there weren't that many). My problem is, I see people recommending a 10 second exposure with an iso of 800, the camera limits the shutter at 8 second up to 1600 iso and 2 second at 3200 and 6400. Will it be enough to capture the milky way?

Comment: Potentially relevent thread by someone with the same camera and the same issue: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3584238

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider when deciding on a camera to take images of the Milky way;

**The Sensor surface area**

•   The s8600 has a surface area of 28mm2 with about 16m Pixels

•   In comparison, a full frame camera such as the Canon 5D IV has a sensor surface area of 864mm2 with over 30m pixels

**Photosites / Pixels**

The larger the photosite/pixel, the more information you will capture of the Milkyway

•   The s8600 has a pixel area of 1.8 micrometre2

•   In comparison, the full frame camera such as the Canon 5D IV has a pixel area of 28.74 micrometre2

As you can see, the Fuji s8600 is already at a great disadvantage

**ISO and Shutter**

Ideally, you need to allow in as much light as possible without capturing the earths movement. Refer to the **500 rule**.

Therefore, if I was to take the widest focal length (25mm), the best ISO (6400) and f-stop (f/2.9) that your S8600 offers and set the full frame Canon 5D with these exact measurements, I can use a maximum shutter speed of 13 Seconds to fill the photosites.

If I want to keep the noise levels down, and dial in at ISO 3200, then I need a shutter speed of 20 Seconds.

Once again, the Fuji s8600 is at great disadvantage as it is not able to achieve this.

**Stacking**

However, all is not lost, and you can try photo stacking 100’s of stills;

•   Depending on what you wish to capture you can use whatever focal length suits your needs

•   Dial in at ISO 3200, f2.9 and shutter speed of 1 or 2 seconds (it will take trial and error over a few days)

•   Then mounted on a tripod, capture between 300x-500x images. ( Also referred to as **light frames**)

•   You will need to manually turn the camera every 30 or so images to keep up with the rotation of the earth.

•   Once these have been captured, you need to capture about 20x **Dark frames**. These are the same settings, but you put the lens cap back on and then just click 20 times

•   And finally, capture about 20x **Bias frames**. These are as above, but with the shutter speed set to the maximum of your camera.

**- for your first trial, take 30-50 Light frames, 5-8 Dark and bias frames and then work from there**

•   Download a piece of software called **Deepskystacker**

•   Before you go to bed, import all of these images into the software and then let your computer churn away till the morning.

•   In the morning, you will have an image where all the images have been stacked, aligned and cropped with sensor noise minimised and maximum light captured.

•   Bring this image into Lightroom and adjust however you wish

Hope this makes some sense and helps you in deciding on how to approach photographing the Milkyway.

My advice, purchase a full frame camera if you are serious about astrophotography.

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice, I'm planning on getting a d810 soon (after my exams)I'll try and see what I can do with this old Fuji till then.